# Module not found with corresponding type declarations using Typescript with Next.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, next.js, babeljs

I have a next.js project that I am trying to add typescript to.

My folder structure is as follows:

```
api
  aggregation.ts
interfaces
  index.ts
components
  Component1
    index.js
    index.module.css
  Component2
    index.js
    index.module.css
pages
  page1
    index.js
    index.module.css
```

I have an alias for `interfaces` in `next.config.js`

```
config.resolve.alias.interfaces = path.join(__dirname, 'interfaces');
```

**Now the actual issue**

`index.ts` in `interfaces` exports interfaces such as

```
 export interface Order {
  store: Store;
  orderNumber: string;
  totals: Totals;
  customer: Customer;
  currency: Currency;
  paymentMethod: PaymentMethod;
  items: OrderProduct[];
  createdAt: string;
  orderId: string;
}
```

And I'm trying to import them into `aggregation.ts` like

```
import { Order } from 'interfaces';
```

And am getting

```
Cannot find module 'interfaces' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

Which is also causing the builds to fail.

I have installed

```
"@types/node": "^16.0.1",
"@types/react": "^17.0.14",
"typescript": "^4.3.5",
```

And next has generated `next-env.d.ts` correctly with

```
/// <reference types="next" />
/// <reference types="next/types/global" />
```

Any ideas on how to fix the `Cannot find module` issue? I have a feeling it may have something to do with my folder structure or my build step. But I am also getting syntax highlighting indicating the import errors so it is probable typescript config related.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried setting up the path aliases in your `tsconfig` as described in [Absolute Imports and Module path aliases](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/module-path-aliases)?

Comment: @juliomalves that worked! Thanks! Solved! Post as an answer so I can mark it

Comment: As @juliomalves above has stated you need to add a // tsconfig.json if you want to run TS inside your next.js project. Here is the documentation: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/module-path-aliases

Answer (score 0):

You can configure module aliases in your `tsconfig.json` using the `baseUrl` option to import directly from the root (and also use the `paths` option for further aliases configuration).

```json
// tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "."
    }
}
```

Allowing you to use the following import.

```js
import { Order } from 'interfaces';
```

From the [Absolute Imports and Module path aliases](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/module-path-aliases) documentation:

> Next.js automatically supports the `tsconfig.json` and `jsconfig.json`
> `"paths"` and `"baseUrl"` options since Next.js 9.4.
>
> These options allow you to configure module aliases, for example a
> common pattern is aliasing certain directories to use absolute paths.
>
> One useful feature of these options is that they integrate
> automatically into certain editors, for example VSCode.
>
> The `baseUrl` configuration option allows you to import directly from
> the root of the project.